# Grails controller inserting two rows in table while i m calling only once

Tags: grails, grails-orm

same value inserted twice in one call

```
class SiteLogsController {

def scaffold =true

def createsitelog={

    def result=[]
        if(params.ip == "")
        {
               result=[erro:"no log set"]

        }
        else
        {
            def sitelog=new SiteLogs(ips:"any text")
            if(!sitelog.save())
            {
                result=[error:"error creating log"]
            }
            else
            {

                result=[success:"log creates"]
            }

        }

        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        render result as JSON        


}

}
```

and values inserted in my table when i call the url for above controller in one call it inserting two value never faced such problem before

```
id    ips
21    params.ip
22    params.ip
```

thanks for your precious time

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're not calling it twice? Some `log.debug` will make you sure.

Comment: Are you calling this controller from any kind of dialog or popup ?

Comment: for inserting values in table i m just tying to insert using this url http://localhost:8078/mysite/siteLogs/createsitelog?ip=123

Comment: I checked your code in a clean project and it works as expected. Only one record is inserted, maybe a 'grails clean' would help?

Comment: thank you all for your valuable suggestion my code finally works i just cleaned everything restart the pc created new database and redeployed my war file and it working i dont know what was the error but it was painfull thanks all

Comment: @spiderman - Since you found the solution, consider either A) posting it as an answer if you think it will help others, or B) removing this question (there's a 'delete' link above the comments here). Glad you got around your problem!

Comment: sitelog.save(flush:true)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters.  It appears to be an issue of duplicate form submissions (e.g. user is double-clicking a button), and the fix is to use form tokens on the server-side or javascript on the client-side.  See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#formtokens